# Mvvmcross - Xamarin native: is deeplinking possible?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, deep-linking

Is deep linking possible in MVVMCROSS for native xamarin (Not Xamarin Forms). If yes, can anyone provide an example of the implementation.

I want to move from view A -> B -> C -> D. When I click on a button on View A I want to move directly to View D but when user clicks on back navigation they should be sent to View C not view A.

Comment: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1315